# is it possible to pop up a dialog using async task

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-asynctask

Let say i am running activity A. I want to write an `AsyncTask` which will pop up a dialog on activity A. was thinking of creating a broadcast receiver that will do this but it seems kinda backwards to me.
not as familiar with `AsyncTask`

```
Intent topop = this.getIntent();
String str = topop.getStringExtra("key1");
if(str.equals("message"))
    dialog.show();
```

another thing: how does `getIntent()` work? if i send repetitive intents? will it only catch the first one?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? AsyncTasks are meant to perform long running operations in the background, so they have no relationship with a pop up dialog (other than to show one to say "loading", or query initial info).

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to pop up a dialog using async task

Yes it is very much possible :)

You can do it in `onPreExecute` or in `onPostExecute` because these two methods are called in UI Thread.

**Never Try to popup dialog in doInBackground method because this method runs in non-ui thread**

Comment: so i just write an Async task and no matter from where i fire it up, if i do dialog.show(); in onPostExecute it will pop it up on main UI-thread which is technically my activity?

Comment: context being the class which is activity A

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask is designed as a convenience (helper class) to allow you to do some background work and deliver the results to the UI. In Android, you 1) cannot block the main ("ui") thread for more than a few seconds before receiving an "application not responding" message and 2) you cannot manipulate the UI from off of the main thread; hence the idea behind asynctask. Having explained that and, assuming I understand your question correctly, you can popup a dialog inside the AsyncTask in either `onPreExecute` or `onPostExecute`. You only cannot do it inside of `doInBackground`.

Comment: could u please que me on the template of the said Async task. i plan on calling it in class C and for it to pop on class A.

Comment: Here's an example of a reusable AsyncTask. https://github.com/levinotik/ReusableAsyncTask you shouldnt have an asynctask as an inner class in one Activity to be used in another. Just make it a top level class, pass in the context to the asynctask and use that context to show the dialog

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just call `dialog.show()` in runOnUiThread().

```
yourActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        dialog.show();
    }
});
```

More about UI Threads: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html